# Configuring 'audit' facility in syslog-ng on solaris server?

Tags: solaris, syslog, syslog-ng, syslogd

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/406522/moving-from-syslog-conf-to-syslogng-conf/406578#comment426524_406578).  mghocke was kind enough to help me out with that question, but this is really a separate question, therefor a new post.

I really don't know a lot about syslog, and am trying to move away from syslogd to syslog-ng.

In Solaris' syslogd, there is an 'audit' facility that you can see configured below:

```
local7.debug                                    /var/log/ncolog
audit.debug                                     /var/log/ncolog
local7.debug                                    @nimitz
audit.debug                                     @nimitz
```

In my new syslog-ng.conf, it is configured like this:

```
filter f_local7 { facility (local7); };
filter f_audit { facility (audit); };
```

...

```
log { source (s_sys); filter (f_local7); destination (d_ncolog); destination (d_nimitz); };
log { source (s_sys); filter (f_audit); destination (d_ncolog); destination (d_nimitz); };
```

But syslog-ng doesn't recognize the 'audit' facility.  I've looked around some, and it seems that the 'audit' facility is facility 13, but 'local13' doesn't work.  What is this facility called in syslog-ng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the symbolic name 'audit' you have to use the numeric code 13:

```
filter f_audit { facility (13); };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again.  Sorry I attributed the wrong user above, I'm an idiot.  It's been fixed.

Comment: If I want to keep the local7 and audit logs out of /var/adm/messages, would changing the first line of the f_messages filter to this work?: `filter f_messages { priority (err..emerg) and not facility (local7) and not facility (13) or`

Comment: Yup, you got it.